# Error: The method 'didChangeDependencies' isn't defined for the class 'ProxyProvider<CategoriesRepository, CategoryBloc>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I updated Provider package. Now it's not wroking.

```
 ProxyProvider<CategoriesRepository, CategoryBloc>(
              update: (context, categoryRepo, categoryBloc) =>//builder:
                  CategoryBloc(categoryRepository: categoryRepo),
              dispose: (context, categoryBloc) => categoryBloc.dispose(),
            ).didChangeDependencies(context, categoryBloc).deleteEntry();
```

**Full Error**

> lib/screens/home/widgets/drawer.dart:297:15: Error: The method
>   'didChangeDependencies' isn't defined for the class
>   'ProxyProvider'.
>    - 'ProxyProvider' is from 'package:provider/src/proxy_provider.dart' ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-4.0.0/lib/src/proxy_provider.dart').
>    - 'CategoriesRepository' is from 'package:yellochat/repository/category_repository.dart'
>   ('lib/repository/category_repository.dart').
>    - 'CategoryBloc' is from 'package:yellochat/screens/categories/category_bloc.dart'
>   ('lib/screens/categories/category_bloc.dart'). Try correcting the name
>   to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named
>   'didChangeDependencies'.
>               ).didChangeDependencies(context, categoryBloc).deleteEntry();

Answer (score 0):

Doing that was never supported and is anti pattern.

Just call your method directly inside `update`